# How to display less html text by default using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to using javascript but was unable to find a question related to my case. I have a page on a site that i want to show less text when the page loads so that visitors can click the read more link to learn more about that particular service. Currently all text is displayed when the page loads and i also noticed some text truncated. How do i fix both issues? Here's the site link

http://www.urbanops.com.ng/services.php

Below is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 250; // no of characters i want shown by default when page loads
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Show less";
var lesstext = "Show more";


$(".more").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle(300);
    $(this).prev().toggle(300);
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Rather than thinking about this in characters, why not in line height?  You can fix the container height and leverage the [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) CSS property to automatically add ellipses.  And then when clicking more you could simply remove/unset the fixed height and let the container grow to whatever size it wants to be given its content?

Comment: @anied here is the css i wrote .more {
 height: 180px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
} that should fix the truncated text but how do i then show the read more link? Like i said i'm new with javascript so i'm on a learning curve

Comment: @Mena-- yeah, that looks right.

Comment: @anied now how do i view the remaining part of the text? I don't see ... at the end or a link to do that. I'm assuming that with this bit of css, i do not need the javascript anymore. Do i?

Comment: You could use JavaScript just to remove the class with that css, and then the div would show full height. You could add a css transition if desired.